# PHP - get date by timezone

Tags: php, date

How I can get the current date of a specific timezone, then convert it to my timezone? For example:

```
$timezone = "UTC+1"; // or UTC, UTC-5, UTC+2....
$date = date($timezone); 
$date_UTC = convert($date, "UTC");
```

So the final return must be something like "2014-02-14 08:25:00 pm +00";

I played around with many functions, but most of them they use timezone like "Europe/France".

Thanks

Comment: You are aware that you can _set_ the timezone, even dynamically … right?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class in conjunction with [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) class:

```
$current_tz_str = date_default_timezone_get();
$current_tz = new DateTimeZone($current_tz_str);
$now = new DateTime('now', $current_tz);
$offset = $current_tz->getOffset($now);
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the timezone with:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

> date_default_timezone_set — Sets the default timezone used by all
>   date/time functions in a script

[see php.net/](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: This is a bad idea for the exact reason in the quote you provided. It sets the timezone for *all* functions in the script. Most likely this operation should be relegated to a specific function or set of statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime` extension to set timezones:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Copenhagen');
$datetime = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
echo '<pre>In Copenhagen: ', $datetime->format('r'), '</pre>';

$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Helsinki');
$datetime->setTimezone($timezone);
echo '<pre>In Helsinki: ', $datetime->format('r'), '</pre>';
```

Which would give you something like:

> In Copenhagen: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 22:01:31 +0100
>
> In Helsinki: Fri, 14 Feb 2014 23:01:31 +0200

Here is a [list of supported timezones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: To whoever down-voted: Please tell me what is wrong with my answer.